# How to remove single quotations from json value

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Json from a api is returning special characters and I want to remove them as its causing issues

This is part of the json;

```
    [
        {
            "id": "email",
            "value": "Email\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b"
        },
        {
            "id": "email",
            "value": "xxx@email.com\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f"
        },
        {
            "id": "email",
            "value": "xxx@email.com\u0001"
        }
    ]
```

I just want the email not the characters after the backslash

Ive tried trim() and preg_match.

```
    $maps_json = file_get_contents('ats.json');
    $maps_array = json_decode($maps_json);

    var_dump(str_split($maps_array[0]->value));
```

the above returns this, I want to remove all other characters after email address.;

```
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "E"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "m"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "i"
      [4]=>
      string(1) "l"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "
      [6]=>
      string(1) "
      [7]=>
      string(1) "
      [8]=>
      string(1) "
      [9]=>
      string(1) "
      [10]=>
      string(1) "
      [11]=>
      string(1) "
      [12]=>
      string(1) "
    }
```

as you can see this value has extra characters that Im not sure how to remove

Comment: use `var_dump(array_filter(str_split($maps_array[0]->value)));`

Comment: no luck with that

Comment: please add your solution as an answer to your question, so that other will get help. Also add this link in your answer for further study:- https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should force the json source not to provide you the backslash signs, however if you cannot do this, try this:

```
$json= str_replace(["\b","\f"], "", $json);
$maps_array = (json_decode($json));
var_dump(str_split($maps_array[0]->value));
```

**Output:**

```
array(5) {
[0]=>
 string(1) "E"
 [1]=>
 string(1) "m"
 [2]=>
 string(1) "a"
 [3]=>
 string(1) "i"
 [4]=>
 string(1) "l"
}
```

Remove the backslash signs with str_replace. However if you have more special signs there \r\n\t you could consider more advanced character removal function.